# How to read a CSV with semicolon delimiters and very long fields in Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a bunch of CSV files that contain some fields, including one with a rough conversion of a PDF to text (with file metadata and digital signature included in the text, without a better specified encoding of the conversion).

The problem is that, by using the `csv package`, Python keeps reading the CSVs without some fields:

```
<field 1,1>;"all the weird clobs you can imagine inside; yes semicolumn too and a lot of combination of \something [...]";"another big field here [...]";<field 1,n>;
.
.
.
<field m,1>;"all the weird clobs you can imagine inside [...]";"another big field here [...]";<field m,n>;
```

resulting in something like

```
<field 1,1>;;;<field 1,n>
.
.
.
<field m,1>;;;<field m,n>
```

I've also **tried different encodings** (I think all of the available ones) when reading the CSV in Python, but still can't seem to get anywhere.

The only way to proceed I've found so far is to open the *CSV* through Excel; import the data from the CSV;
transform them into **.xlsm* and then continue the processing in Python.
Even doing that those fields are so large that they exceed the [*32,767 characters* per cell that Excel can handle](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3).

Excel performs the transformation using the semicolon as the separator and 65001:Unicode (UTF-8) as the
encoding.

The problem is that I have thousands of these files and can handle 30 CSVs per hour (importing takes time to parse the file and get the data). Obviously this workaround is not feasible.

Can't share such files, but I hope the situation is clear enough

**Edit 1:**

This is what I get when I try to open them with pandas:

```
>>> pd.read_csv('0.csv')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\me\.conda\envs\AI_LIMe\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\me\.conda\envs\AI_LIMe\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 586, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\me\.conda\envs\AI_LIMe\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 488, in _read
    return parser.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\me\.conda\envs\AI_LIMe\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1047, in read
    index, columns, col_dict = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\me\.conda\envs\AI_LIMe\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\c_parser_wrapper.py", line 223, in read
    chunks = self._reader.read_low_memory(nrows)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 801, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read_low_memory
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 857, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 843, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1925, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 46, saw 2
```

when reading with the `csv package`:

```
In [1]: import csv

In [2]: with open('0.csv', encoding='utf-8') as csvreader:
   ...:     rows = []
   ...:     for row in csvreader:
   ...:         rows.append(row)
   ...:
```

simply got the `row` without the pdf as text:

```
In [3]: row
Out[3]: '  ";{http://schemas.[protected_text_here]v1}:kind1;/mnt/repository/2018-03-26/IDX_000000_1.0;TEXT;S;111111;1;2016;DF;;;01;DPDDPDDPD03I8333;288;16078169k94404433920;CST;GLCZ;;;184046_;2018-03-26T19:23:07Z\n'
```

Comment: Python by itself does no such thing. The easiest explanation by far is that you are reading the CSV file incorrectly, but without your code and a sample file, we really can't tell you anything more. Please [edit] to provide a [mre].

Comment: CSV is inherently a text format, and Unicode is a particularly bad choice for trying to serialize binary data. If you can influence the data representation, a better design would store just a file name, and read the blob of binary directly from that file.

Comment: unfortunately I can't. Files come in this terrible format and It's no possible to take any other action to change them.
Trying to reproduce the problem with some safe-to-share files... But I think the problem is in serialization itself. The only information I got on creation is the one contained into text itself:  "producer Microsoft® Word 2010; modified using iText® 5.4.5 ©2000-2013 1T3XT BVBA (AGPL-version) "

Comment: I'm afraid your edit only reinforces what we already told you. You are reading the CSV incorrectly, or it's simply invalid; but without any information about how the hidden data is encoded, you are on your own. Experiment with different escaping regimes, or reveal enough data to let us help you understand what you are looking at.

Comment: I would suggest using a pool of process workers using the multiprocessing module, so you can get more CPU cores chewing on these files concurrently.

Comment: You are using "csvreader" incorrectly. As it stands, `csvreader` is a _simple file handle_, and iterating over it gives you a plain old string for each line in the file. To read a csv file you actually need to create a `csv.reader` or similar object from the `csv` module, which you can then iterate over to get the rows _parsed as if they were from a csv file_. See [Paul's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71213356/843953) for how to specify a non-comma delimiter

Answer (score 2):

If your delimiters are not commas, then you just need to tell csv that you expect to see ';' characters between fields, with the optional `delimiter` argument (which defaults to ',').

I almost always use csv DictReader to read csv files. Here it is with your semicolon-delimited data set:

```
data = """\
<field 1,1>;"all the weird clobs you can imagine inside; yes semicolumn too and a lot of combination of \something [...]";"another big field here [...]";<field 1,n>;
<field m,1>;"all the weird clobs you can imagine inside [...]";"another big field here [...]";<field m,n>;"""

import csv
from pprint import pprint

for row in csv.DictReader(data.splitlines(),
                          fieldnames="f1 f2 f3 f4 f5".split(),
                          delimiter=';'):
    pprint(row, width=132)
```

Prints:

```
{'f1': '<field 1,1>',
 'f2': 'all the weird clobs you can imagine inside; yes semicolumn too and a lot of combination of \\something [...]',
 'f3': 'another big field here [...]',
 'f4': '<field 1,n>',
 'f5': ''}

{'f1': '<field m,1>',
 'f2': 'all the weird clobs you can imagine inside [...]',
 'f3': 'another big field here [...]',
 'f4': '<field m,n>',
 'f5': ''}
```

Comment: `csv.*reader` take a `delimiter=';'` keyword argument, so you don't need to define a dialect class.

Comment: Could have sworn I tried that, but maybe I used "separator". Thanks, will fix (much simpler!).

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to make available the solution I found, I hope It can help someone.

Solution:

```
with open('0.csv', 'r',  newline='\r', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile.read().splitlines(), delimiter=';')
        for row in reader:
            print(', '.join(row))
```

Comment: Apart from the inefficent reading of the whole file into memory before passing it to the `csv.reader`, this is how you read _any_ `csv` file. Not specifying the delimiter defaults to comma (that's what the C in CSV stands for) so obviously you need to do that if your file uses a different delimiter.